# Trying to create a custom tooltip in a doughnut chart using chartsjs, but it is not working

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have a 2-part question:

**Question 1:**
I am trying to create a custom tooltip for the doughnut chart I have, using chartsjs.  I am getting an issue where when I run the code (on jsfiddle) the doughnut chart appears but when I hover over it, it disappears. 
I get the following error message: ***Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null.***

**Question 2:** I am trying to add a second tooltip, but a custom one into the doughnut I have. I have it saved as the following: labels2 = ["one", "two", "three"]. I followed the documentation for custom tooltips in [chartsjs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#external-custom-tooltips)  and I created a function that I thought would display the tooltip, which I currently have labeled as label2 in the Fiddle. (Line 105). However, it is not functioning. 
https://jsfiddle.net/silosc/51pja7ze/36/

```
Here is the code for the function:

// HTML
    <canvas id="myChart" height="100"></canvas>

    //JS    
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow"],
    labels2: ["One", "Two", "Three"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
     // Disable the on-canvas tooltip
        enabled: false,
      custom: function(tooltipModel){
        // Tooltip Element
                var tooltipEl = document.getElementById("myChart");

            // Create element on first render
            if (!tooltipEl){
            tooltipEl = document.getElementById("div");
            tooltipEl.id = 'myChart';
            tooltipEL.innerHTML = '<table></table>';
            document.body.appendChild(tooltipEl);
            }

             // Hide if no tooltip
            if (tooltipModel.opacity === 0){
            tooltipEl.style.opacity = 0;
            return;
            }

             // Set caret Position
            tooltipEl.classList.remove('above', 'below', 'no-transform');
            if (tooltipModel.yAlign) {
            tooltipEl.classList.add(tooltipModel.yAlign);
            } else {
            tooltipEl.classList.add('no-transform');
            }

            function getBody(bodyItem) {
             return bodyItem.lines;
            }
            // Set Text
             if (tooltipModel.body) {
                    var titleLines = tooltipModel.title || [];
                    var bodyLines = tooltipModel.body.map(getBody);

                    var innerHtml = '<thead>';

                    titleLines.forEach(function(title) {
                        innerHtml += '<tr><th>' + title + '</th></tr>';
                    });
                    innerHtml += '</thead><tbody>';

                    bodyLines.forEach(function(body, i) {
                        var colors = tooltipModel.labelColors[i];
                        var style = 'background:' + colors.backgroundColor;
                        style += '; border-color:' + colors.borderColor;
                        style += '; border-width: 2px';
                        var span = '<span style="' + style + '"></span>';
                        innerHtml += '<tr><td>' + span + body + '</td></tr>';
                    });
                    innerHtml += '</tbody>';

                    var tableRoot = tooltipEl.querySelector('table');
                    tableRoot.innerHTML = innerHtml;
                }

                // `this` will be the overall tooltip
               var position = this._chart.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

                 tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
                tooltipEl.style.position = 'absolute';
                tooltipEl.style.left = position.left + window.pageXOffset + tooltipModel.caretX + 'px';
                tooltipEl.style.top = position.top + window.pageYOffset + tooltipModel.caretY + 'px';
                tooltipEl.style.fontFamily = tooltipModel._bodyFontFamily;
                tooltipEl.style.fontSize = tooltipModel.bodyFontSize + 'px';
                tooltipEl.style.fontStyle = tooltipModel._bodyFontStyle;
                tooltipEl.style.padding = tooltipModel.yPadding + 'px ' + tooltipModel.xPadding + 'px'
                tooltipEl.style.pointerEvents = 'none';



      },
      callbacks: {
        title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          return data['labels'][tooltipItem[0]['index']];
        },
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          return data['datasets'][0]['data'][tooltipItem['index']];
        },
        label2: function(tooltipItem, data){
            return data['data'][0]['data'][tooltipItem['index']];
        },
        afterLabel: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          var dataset = data['datasets'][0];
          var percent = Math.round((dataset['data'][tooltipItem['index']] / dataset["_meta"][0]['total']) * 100)
          return '(' + percent + '%)';
        }
      },
      backgroundColor: '#FFF',
      titleFontSize: 16,
      titleFontColor: '#0066ff',
      bodyFontColor: '#000',
      bodyFontSize: 14,
      displayColors: false
    }
  }
});
```

Can somebody help me out?  I have never done a custom tooltip, so this is a first for me and I am lost.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding question 1:
Everything disappears because you are using your chart-canvas as tooltip element and thus it gets emptied:
var tooltipEl = document.getElementById("myChart");

If you stick to the example provided in the documentation (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#external-custom-tooltips), it should set you on your way.
So instead of

```
var tooltipEl = document.getElementById("myChart");

        // Create element on first render
        if (!tooltipEl){
        tooltipEl = document.getElementById("div");
        tooltipEl.id = 'myChart';
        tooltipEL.innerHTML = '<table></table>';
        document.body.appendChild(tooltipEl);
        }
```

Use

```
var tooltipEl = document.getElementById('chartjs-tooltip');

            // Create element on first render
            if (!tooltipEl) {
                tooltipEl = document.createElement('div');
                tooltipEl.id = 'chartjs-tooltip';
                tooltipEl.innerHTML = '<table></table>';
                document.body.appendChild(tooltipEl);
            }
```